# QT Opencv Android app cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android6Camera10disconnectEv"

Tags: android, qt, opencv

Created an Opencv and QT based app. The code works fine for Desktop version but the Android version when starts throws following exception,

dlopen("/data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.test-1/libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android6Camera10disconnectEv" referenced by "libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so"...

W/System.err(25902): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
W/System.err(25902):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)....
.....

Note: I have OpenCV manager installed on my Android phone.

Made changes to include only libopencv_java.so library rather than all those in libs folder. Now getting following errors,

> I/Qt      (19448): qt start
>
> I/Qt      (19448): Sensors start
>
> W/art     (19448): Thread[14,tid=19502,Native,Thread*=0x48416278,peer=0x656c9238,"Thread-6047"] attached without supplying a name
>
> I/Adreno-EGL(19448): : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
>
> W/art     (19448): Thread[14,tid=19502,Native,Thread*=0x48416278,peer=0x656ca3c8,"Thread-6048"] attached without supplying a name
>
> W/art     (19448): Thread[14,tid=19502,Native,Thread*=0x48416278,peer=0x656ca600,"Thread-6049"] attached without supplying a name
>
> D/OpenGLRenderer(19448): Enabling debug mode 0
>
> D/OpenCV::camera(19448): CvCapture_Android::CvCapture_Android(0)
>
> D/OpenCV::camera(19448): Library name: libopencv_java.so
>
> D/OpenCV::camera(19448): Library base address: 0x49834000
>
> D/OpenCV::camera(19448): Libraries folder found: /data/app-lib/com.sumit.tracker-1/
>
> D/OpenCV::camera(19448): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib: folderPath=/data/app-/lib/com.sumit.tracker-1/
>
> E/OpenCV::camera(19448): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library
>
> E/OpenCV::camera(19448): Native_camera returned opening error: 4
>
> D/OpenCV::camera(19448): CvCapture_Android::CvCapture_Android(98)
>
> D/OpenCV::camera(19448): Library name: libopencv_java.so
>
> D/OpenCV::camera(19448): Library base address: 0x49834000
>
> D/OpenCV::camera(19448): Libraries folder found: /data/app-lib/com.sumit.tracker-1/
>
> D/OpenCV::camera(19448): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib: folderPath=/data/app-lib/com.sumit.tracker-1/
>
> E/OpenCV::camera(19448): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library
>
> E/OpenCV::camera(19448): Native_camera returned opening error: 4
>
> E/cv::error()(19448): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3737
>   F/libc    (19448): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00004bf8 (code=-6), thread 19502 (QtThread-114216)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of exploring found out this link,

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-qt/1238egc0ef/recommendations-for-camera-access

Discussion on the page suggests following,

Add the following libraries as LIBS to .pro file,

> 1] libopencv_info.so
>
> 2] libopencv_java.so

Also, copy these libraries to the android/libs folder of your project. This shall solve all the issues mentioned above in the question.